# Isomorphism from $B[y]/IB[y]$ onto $(B/I)[y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

For some reason I can't crack the following problem:

> Let $B$ be a ring, $I$ an ideal, and $A := B[y]$ the polynomial ring.
>   Construct an isomorphism from $A/IA$ onto $(B/I)[y]$.

How to interpret the (polynomial) quotient ring $A/IA$? And how do I construct the isomorphism knowing this?

Hope you can help!

Comment: IA is generated by all A-multiples of $I$, so it's cosets up to things which are sums of elements of the form $ia$, $i\in I$, $a\in A$.

Comment: I would like to suggest you to analyze the kernel of the following surjective ring homomorphism $B[y] \to (B/I) [y]$.

Comment: @user26857 (and Youngsu!), thank you!
Ahh, $IB[y]$ is the set of poylnomials with coefficients in $I$! This is exactly the kernel of the surjective isomorphism $\varphi : B[y] \to (B/I)[y]$. So by the first isomorphism theorem, $(B/I)[y] \cong B[y]/IB[y]$. I feel I'm getting really close. How do I construct the isomorphism from this?

Comment: @user26857 Ah, because it sends a polynomial into the same polynomial with coefficients reduced modulo $I$ it is injective hence an isomorphism. But it seems this is an isomorphism from $B[y]$ onto $(B/I)[y]$ and not $B[y]/IB[y]$ onto $(B/I)[y]$ as it should?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the natural *surjective* homomorphism $B \to B/I,$ where $b \in B \mapsto b + I \in B/I.$ Show that that induces a *surjective* homomorphism $h: B[y] \to (B/I)[y],$ where a polynomial $f(y) = b_ny^n +b_{n-1}y^{n-1}+ \cdots+b_0 \in B[y]$  gets mapped to $(b_n + I)y^n +(b_{n-1} + I)y^{n-1}+ \cdots+(b_0+I).$

Now to establish the isomorphism using the *first isomorphism theorem*, we need to prove that the kernel of $B[y] \to (B/I)[y]$ is precisely the ideal $IB[y]$ (*i.e.* the ideal $I,$ now generated in $B[y].$) Look closely at the definition of an ideal, where now

$$IB[y] = \{a_my^m+a_{m-1}y^{m-1}+\cdots+a_0| \; a_i \in I, \; \forall 1 \leq i \leq m  \}.$$

Clearly any element of $IB[y]$ lies in the kernel of $h$ as

$$a_my^m+a_{m-1}y^{m-1}+\cdots+a_0 \mapsto (a_m+I)y^m+(a_{m-1}+I)y^{m-1}+\cdots+(a_0+I)$$

via $h,$ where $a_i+I = I$ for all $1 \leq i \leq m$ because $a_i \in I$ (by definition). Therefore $(a_m+I)y^m+(a_{m-1}+I)y^{m-1}+\cdots+(a_0+I) = 0$ in $(B/I)[y].$ Hence the $IB[y]$ is contained $ \subseteq$ in the kernel of $h$. Now we need to show that the kernel is contained in $IB[y]$ in order to prove the equality. Take an element of the kernel $g(y) = c_ky^k+\cdots+c_0.$ As it is in the kernel it means that all $c_i \in I$ otherwise it won't be an element of the kernel.

P.S. I tried to explain as extensive as possible and I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your very thorough description! Definitely made sense (was also the pieces that I had put together). What I am still wondering though, is where is the ''constructed isomorphism'' to quote the problem? We needed to construct an isomorphism from $A/IA$ onto $(B/I)[y]$, but all I can see is that we have shown them to be isomorphic? Or is $h$ the isomorphism?

Comment: Dear @BoSchmidt, $h$ is *not* the isomorphism but it induces an isomorphism say $\overline{h}: B[y] / \text{ker}(h) \to (B/I)[y].$ You may take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Discussion

Comment: @EhsanMKermani Ahh, I get it now. Perfect. Thank you!