# Prove the ideal $(f)$ is not maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $B$ be a UFD and $A := B[y]$ the polynomial ring. Let $f$ be a
>   polynomial that has a term $by^i$ with $i > 0$ such that $b$ is not
>   divisible by some prime element $p$ in $B$. Prove that the ideal $(f)$
>   is not maximal.

Since $b$ is not divisible by some prime element $p \in B$, $b$ must be a prime itself. So the problem is asking us to prove that a polynomial with coefficients in a UFD with a coefficient that is prime does not generate a maximal ideal.

I have tried proving that $(f)$ is not a prime ideal (hence not maximal), but that didn't work out. I also thought of showing that $(f)$ must be contained in some larger ideal that is not equal to $B[y]$, e.g. $(f) \subset (pf)$ for some prime $p \in B$, but I think there is equality there. So I haven't been able to find an ideal in which $(f)$ must be contained. I know that an ideal ideal $I$ in a commutative ring $R$ is maximal if $I \subset J$ implies $J=I$ or $J=R$.

Can you help?

Comment: I don't think this is true. Say $B=\mathbb{F}$, a field, and let $f(y)=y$.

Comment: @Bo Schmidt: I don't think that $b$ is prime. There is only *some* (i.e. at least one) prime $p$ such that $p$ doesn't divide $b$. At least this is how I would read the problem.

Comment: We should re-write the condition on $b$ as follows : there exists a term $by^i$ with $i > 0$ and a prime $p$ such that $p$ does not divide $b$. It got me confused at first, but this is clearer. Then it is clear that we cannot assume $B$ is a field because fields have no prime elements.

Comment: Ahh, yes of course. I totally misread that one! Haha. Thank you! And nice find @AdamHughes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p$ be a prime such that $p\nmid b$. We have $(f)\subsetneq (p,f)$, and for proving that $(f)$ isn't maximal it's enough to show that $(p,f)\ne B[y]$. Assume the contrary: $(p,f)=B[y]$. Then $B[y]/(p,f)=0$. On the other side, $$B[y]/(p,f)\simeq \frac{B/(p)[y]}{(\bar f)},$$ where $\bar f$ is the image of $f$ in $B/(p)[y]$, and therefore $\bar f$ is invertible in $B/(p)[y]$, so $\deg\bar f=0$. (Note that $B/(y)$ is a field.) Since $p\nmid b$, we get that $y^i$ survives in $\bar f$, a contradiction.

Comment: Since we need a *non-zero* prime $p$ with $p\nmid b$ (in order to have $(f)\subsetneq (p,f)$), we assume that $B$ is not a field.

Comment: Your proof that $(p,f)$ is not maximal is kind of disturbing... I'd rather go with this : there exists $g,h \in B[y]$ such that $gp + fh = 1$, which means $fh = 1 \pmod{p B[y]}$ in the polynomial ring $B[y]/pB[y] \simeq (B/pB)[y]$. The condition on $f$ shows that $\deg(fh) > 0$, a contradiction. Maybe it's just me, but I feel my phrasing less disturbing. Feel free to judge by yourself. Eitherway +1 for the proof

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Your proof makes a little more sense to me. Only thing I'm missing is why do we have $B[y]/pB[y] \cong (B/pB)[y]$? @ user26857 I will read through your proof a couple of times :) Thanks so much for your help both of you!

Comment: @BoSchmidt Use [this previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856023/isomorphism-from-by-iby-onto-b-iy) posted by you with $I=(p)$.

Comment: @user26857 Yes, I tried that but thought something was amiss. In the previous question, $B[y]$ is a polynomial ring and $I$ an ideal, and we have the isomorphism $B[y]/IB[y] \cong (B/I)[y]$. I tried $I=(p)$ but that gives $B[y]/(p)B[y] \cong (B/(p))[y]$, whereas Patrick wrote $B[y]/pB[y] \cong (B/pB)[y]$. Maybe it's just me misinterpreting, but it seems in Patricks isomorphism $p$ just occurs as the element and not the ideal generated by $p$?

Comment: @BoSchmidt He uses a different notation for the ideal generated by $p$, that is, $pB$ instead of $(p)$, respectively $pB[y]$ instead of $(p)B[y]$.

Comment: @user26857 Ahh, I get it! Sorry :) Hadn't seen that before but it makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: Yes @Bo Schmidt I confirm the other comment, writing $pB$ for $(p)B$ is a common number theory habit.